# Sending values to another function using structures - Whats wrong with that?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, struct

I have two functions and a structure. My first function `getChange` does calculations and stores them in two arrays. My second function `printChange` should accept these values of two arrays and just print arrays using a simple `for` loop.

I am trying to use my structure `Change` to send these arrays across to the print function, but I can't seem to do it.

I thought of creating two arrays in my structure and then simply setting array in function = to array in struct and then do the opposite in print func. But I can't!

```
# include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct cashback{
    int value[8];
    int money[8];
};
typedef struct cashback Change;

int getChange(int paid, int cost){
    int r, k, cntr, c=1, value[8], money[8]={200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1};

    Change store;

    if (cost>paid){
        printf("\t Insufficient Funds! \n");
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }
    r=paid-cost;
    value[0]=r/money[0];
    k=r%money[0];   
    for(money[c], cntr=1;cntr<8;c++, cntr++){

        if (k !=0){
            value[c]= k/money[c];
            k=k%money[c];
        }
        else{
            value[c]=0;
            k=k/money[c];
        }

    }
    store.value[8]=value[8];
    store.money[8]=money[8]; //Sending calculation to Struct(store)

}

void printChange() {
    Change store;
    int i, j; 
    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        printf("%i \t",store.money[i] );
    }
    printf("\n \n");

    for (j=0; j<8; j++) {
        printf("%i \t ", store.value[j] );
        }

}

int main(){

    Change store;
    getChange(90,50);
    printChange();


    getchar();

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your struct?

Comment: Updated :) please check now ^

Comment: What is `va`? If you don't use the function `printChange` and it isn't related to the problem. Please do remove it for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: `store.value[8]=value[8];store.money[8]=money[8];` is an error. The array has dimension 8 which means the valid indices are `0` through to `7`. If you mean to copy all indices from `0` through to `7`, you can't substitute `8` for that... you will need to write a loop or use the `memcpy` function. Although an easier solution would be to not use `value` or `money` at all, and just fill in the `Change` object directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
Change store;
```

inside a function, that means there is a variable called `store` *inside that function only*.  In your code you have three separate variables (all called `store`).

Instead you need to *pass* the variable around where it is needed.

You currently have `getChange` returning `int` but you never actually return a value. Instead you should make this return the change:

```
Change getChange(int paid, int cost)
{
    Change change;
    // ...
    return change;
}
```

Similarly, the `printChange` function should be:

```
void printChange(Change change)
{
    // ...
}
```

and your main function will look like:

```
Change store;
store = getChange(90, 50);
printChange(store);
```

Comment: it wont return change "variable used without bein initialized"

Comment: @CcoderBeginner in the `...` you put your code that implements the change-getting, similar to what you posted in the question

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all inside the 'getChange', you don't use the 'Change' struct at all. Apart from using it in this declaration: `Change a;`
Also, there is certainly an error here: `a.value =`. With what is equal?
So, the money and value arrays that you declare inside 'getChange' have nothing to do with your struct. 
And finally, it doesn't seem that printChange has anything to do with the rest of the program.

Comment: the a.value was what i was trying to equate with the array in my structure but i got a message that value[8] from my struct could not be modified, and im trying to link my two functions using my struct :S

Comment: @CcoderBeginner Are you trying to assign the same value to all the members of the array?

Comment: @CcoderBeginner Sorry, my friend I really want to help but I cannot understand either what you want to do or what is the actual problem. I recommend that you read a good tutorial about sructs because it seems like you have fundamental questions. If you have a book about C, it will certainly have a chapter about structs. Read it carefully! Otherwise, there is a great tutorial here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm, which might not cover all you need but at least you will learn the basics.

Comment: @Linus basically im trying to copy the results acquired from the calculation to the print function using the structure so i was trying to make the arrays in the struct the same as those acquired from calc.

Comment: @Zuko32 Thanks for the Excellent tut in link, i think my problem is in pointers not structs :/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to both functions pointer to `Change` structure. The structure can be defined inside `main`:

```
int  getChange(int paid, int cost, Change* a){
    //...
    a->value[c] = ...
    //...
}

void printChange(Change* a) {
    //...
    printf("%i \t", a->value[i]);
    //...
}

int main(){
    Change a;
    getChange(90,50, &a);
    getchar(&a);
}
```